# Need to split string with specific exception

Tags: c#, split

Help, I need to split:

> aaa 'bbb c' dd ee fg hjj

with preserving space on the quotation

I tried to use .Split(" ") and ends up with

> aaa
> 'bbb
> c'
> dd
> ee
> fg
> hjj

What I expected is

> aaa
> 'bbb c'
> dd
> ee
> fg
> hjj

Can anyone kindly help me?

Comment: What language/framework?

Comment: visual studio c# language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may just split with " " then as mentioned you will get the wrong results so try looping around this result find all elements beginning with ' character and merge then together until you reach the element that ends with ' character. do not forget to put an space between them.

Comment: i expecting about more neat solution, but this is also works! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this logic:
1) Find the first quotation ' then the next quotation '
You will get the word within quotation. 
Run a loop starting from 1st character to the length of the text doing above activity to extract all words within quotes & store in array. You subsequent search for quote should start from the last quote position+1

2) Next Replace all these quoted words with nothing in your original text.
So you are left with words & spaces only.
Mind it - The point where you have replaced the quoted words have 2 white spaces (leading & trailing). 
So use trim to have only 1 white space.

3) Next use your split on white space to get the individual words

4) Now combine the results of point 1 & point 3 to get your final result

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you want to store the splitted string in memory, or by other side, you just want to show it. I've made a code of a function that split the first string (aa 'bbb c' dd ee fg hjj) in three strings and store them inside of another string array. Then the last one is splitted again by blank spaces and stored again:

```
 static void exampleFunction()
    {
        const int MAXNUM = 20; //The max amount of elements in the second array strings.
        int count = 0;
        int secondCount = 0;
        string text = "aaa 'bbb c' dd ee fg hjj";
        string[] firstTextSplitted = { "" };
        string[] secondTextSplitted = new string[MAXNUM];

        firstTextSplitted = text.Split('\''); //We obtain the following strings: "aaa", "bbb c" and "dd ee fg hjj".

        for (count = 0; count < 3; count++) //We obtain separately the three strings from the first string array.
        {
            if (count == 2) //If we are in the last one, we must split it again and store each element in the followings.
            {
                secondCount = count;

                foreach (string element in firstTextSplitted[count].Split(' '))
                {
                    secondTextSplitted[secondCount] = element;
                    secondCount++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                secondTextSplitted[count] = firstTextSplitted[count];
            }
        }

        foreach (string element in secondTextSplitted) //We print each string value from the second string array, if we dont match a null value.
        {
            if (element != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(element);
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps!